# Get Max Path Sum Recursive with huge 2d array

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have to get the max path sum of a 2d array.
I can manage to get up to 40 rows, but after the function does not return any value.
Can some one help me?

```
private int GetTotal(int row, int column, int[,] triangle)
{
    if (row == 0) return triangle[row, column];

    int myValue = pyramid[row, column];
    int left = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column, triangle);
    int right = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column + 1, triangle);

    return Math.Max(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. On which language exactly? And what have you tried so far? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: And some code please.

Comment: scheien, can I send in an email?

Comment: @user3501919 No, you should post the code and all other necessarily details in the question itself.

Comment: _Can I send in an email?_ **NO!** That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you hire someone, go sites like rent-acoder.com..

Comment: Why email? Stackoverflow editors supports code. you can add it here.

Comment: Edit your original post, paste in your code (Left-justified, KEEP DELINIATION) and select it all and press the code (preformatted) button on the editing toolbar. EDIT: Thank you.

Comment: Please post what `Pyramid` is also.

Comment: and also your `GetTotalAbove` method

Comment: ja72, it is just a 2d array.

Comment: A 2d array would be of `long[,]` or `int[,]` type. Please include all relevant definitions for `Pyramid` and associated methods like `GetTotalAbove()`.

Comment: It is a long[,] 2d array. GetTotalAbove() is GetTotal().  I just edited it.

Comment: So it seems your recursion has caused a `StackOverflowException`. You have come to the place I guess.

Comment: Well, I didn't get an StackOverflowException message but i guess it should be.

Comment: Yes, forty recursions and then bam! = stack overflow.

Comment: How can I overcome it?

Comment: Consider using a `Stack<T>` object and avoid recursions. I am looking at an example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing exponential running time for your algorithm. The algorithm runs in `O(2^rows)` - which is quite a large number.

Consider transforming your code into a [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution, which is basically an efficient way to implement such recursions, without the need to calculate some values twice (which is the case in your code).

Simplest way to do it is *top-down Dynamic Programming*, also known as ["memorization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Simply add a dictionary, let's call it `cache`, and at the beginning of the function - check if (row,column) is in the cache. If it is - just return the already computed value.

Otherwise - compute the value, and before returning it - store it in `cache`.

Here is a **Pseudo code** based on your code. It won't compile - but it should demonstrate the issue at hand.

```
private long GetTotal(int row, int column, Pyramid pyramid, Dictionary<Pair<int,int>,long> cache)
{
    if (row == 0) return pyramid[row, column];
    //add a check if you already calculated for this row and column:
    Pair<int,int> p = new Pair<int,int>(row,column);
    if cache.ContainsKey(p) return cache.Get(p);

    int myValue = pyramid[row, column];
    long left = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column, pyramid, cache); //sending the dictionary as well...
    long right = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column + 1, pyramid, cache);

    long best = Math.Max(left, right);
    //before returning: store the just calculated value in the cache:
    cache.Add(p,best);
    return best;
}
```

Comment: amit, thank you but can you please give me an example?

Comment: @user3501919 If you mean a complete working code - no. What exactly don't you understand? I'll try to elaborate on the specific part. Do you understand what a dictionary is? Do you know how to insert elements to it and get elements from it?

Comment: Yes, I do know dictionary , list and ect, but not clear how to implement in this case.

Comment: @user3501919 I added to your code the concepts that you should add. This will **NOT** compile as is, but it clarifies what should be done.

Comment: Thank you got your help.  I am going to follow it and I let you know.

Comment: Can I ask what is Pair?

Comment: @user3501919 It's implemented in C# as [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

Comment: This is the simpler way?

Comment: @user3501919 The more complex way is using bottom-up DP, which is completely changing your code. The point is - you have calculations you can reach to in various ways, for example GetTotal(5,5) will calculate GetTotal(3,4) once for `GetTotal(5,5)->GetTotal(4,5)->GetTotal(3,4)` and once for `GetTotal(5,5)->GetTotal(4,4)->GetTotal(3,4)` When the size of the pyramid grows - these redundant calculations become more and more significant and slows down the program. Memorization helps you calculate everything only once.

Comment: I am a bit in trouble to understand this concept.  This is the first time I come across.

Comment: @user3501919 It worths learning it. If you have a specific problem, ask - but the modifications to the code you have should be very minimal, it shouldn't take too long to implement it if you are familiar with a Dictionary.

Comment: I am familiar with simple dictionary, but never created in the function header.

Comment: @user3501919 Did you try to follow the links I provided for deeper understanding about Dynamic Programming?

Comment: I read something online and I also I have in some of my books, but I have to complete this task by this week.  Let start with this line "Dictionary<Pair<int,int>,long> cache)" what it actually do?

Comment: @user3501919 It's just a new argument to the method, you can also use an instance variable instead, similar to your `Pyramid pyramid`.

Comment: So, I am digging into it and as example I have a Fibonacci.  Can I used this principle to me method?                                int[] fib = new int[max];
int fibonacci2(int i)
{
    if (i == 0) return 0;
    if (i == 1) return 1;
    if (fib[i] != 0) return fib[i]; // Return cached result.
    fib[i] = fibonacci2(i - 1) + fibonacci2(i - 2); // Cache result.
    return fib[i];
}

Comment: I still cannot manage with the array.  Do you mind to make an example?

Comment: @Orazio I opened a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50528/get-max-path-sum-recursive-with-huge-2d-array) Please write your code - and if you get an exception - the full exception + stacktrace in there and I will try to help you. I will sample it in a few hours and answer when I see your code - there.

Comment: @Orazio Here you go. use it, and let's discuss there.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Amit this is what I have done but now is actually worse.  Now the overflow happen at 25 rows, while before the editing at 40 rows.

```
int[] cache = new int[1000]; 
private int GetTotal(int row, int column, int[,] triangle, int[] cache)
{
    if (row == 0) return triangle[row, column];

    int myValue = triangle[row, column];
    int left = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column, triangle, cache);
    int right = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column + 1, triangle, cache);

    if (cache[row] != 0)
    return cache[row];

    cache[row] = Math.Max(left, right);
    return cache[row];
}
```